# How to properly activate Magnific-popup from within the mb.extrude jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

Plugins used: [mb.extruder](http://pupunzi.com/#mb.components/mb.extruder/extruder.html) and [magnific-popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/)

When using magnific-popup for inline content on my page utilizing code such as:

```
<a href="#test-inline" class="popup-inline" >Inline Content</a>
```

It works perfect. However if I use the same code above as an mb.extruder link then it just treats the link as a normal url and loads the page with /#test-inline.

Here are my jquery functions:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#navSliderTop").buildMbExtruder({
        positionFixed:false,
        width:350,
        extruderOpacity:1,
        autoCloseTime:4000,
        closeOnExternalClick:false,
       // hidePanelsOnClose:false,
        onExtOpen:function(){},
        onExtContentLoad:function(){},
        onExtClose:function(){}
      });

// Pop-up boxes

  $('.popup-inline').magnificPopup({
      type:'inline',
      midClick: true,
      preloader: true
      });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the code for the lightbox in "onExtContentLoad:function(){}"  for it to work.

Note: It works for the main extruder panel which is called via ajax. But not if the link is inside the content of a secondary panel.

So it looks like.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#navSliderTop").buildMbExtruder({
        positionFixed:false,
        width:350,
        extruderOpacity:1,
        autoCloseTime:4000,
        closeOnExternalClick:false,
       // hidePanelsOnClose:false,
        onExtOpen:function(){},
        onExtContentLoad:function(){
 $('.popup-inline').magnificPopup({
      type:'inline',
      midClick: true,
      preloader: true
      });
},
        onExtClose:function(){}
      });




      });
```